# Detect if an alert or confirm is displayed on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

Is there a way using JavaScript or jQuery to detect if a confirm or alert box is being displayed?

Comment: What do you mean by "being displayed" exactly? Do you mean whether there is a reference to the command in the code?

Comment: With Web Workers you could ...

Comment: @Raynos I assume that alerts don't block workers.

Comment: @SimeVidas how do you detect an `alert` ? Other things can block the browser like synchronous waiting on Ajax.

Comment: @Raynos Yes, I'm not sure how to detect the source of the blocking. But workers should be able to detect if the window is blocked or not.

Comment: @SimeVidas that's not detecting an alert. Say you wanted to do some automated testing and assert that the alert worked without human intervention. How would you do that?

Comment: @Raynos It turns out that an alert pop-up will not block the window fully. This demo - http://vidasp.net/tinydemos/worker/main.html - shows that worker-to-window and window-to-worker communication can occur normally even when an alert pop-up is open.

Comment: @SimeVidas I know and expect that. Doesn't help detecting whether an alert is happening.

Answer (score 28):

If you wanted to run some code when an `alert()` fires, you could try something like this:

I've only tested in Chrome, so I'm not sure about browser support.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Q785x/1/

```
(function() {
    var _old_alert = window.alert;
    window.alert = function() {
                     // run some code when the alert pops up
        document.body.innerHTML += "<br>alerting";
        _old_alert.apply(window,arguments);
                     // run some code after the alert
        document.body.innerHTML += "<br>done alerting<br>";
    };
})();

alert('hey');
alert('you');
alert('there');
```

Of course this only lets you run code before and after an alert. As @kander noted, javascript execution is halted while the alert is displayed.

Comment: you have no garantuee that the alert fires. Your assuming that window.alert is correctly implemented!

Comment: @Raynos: If you're talking about browser support, yes I am assuming. I noted in my answer that I've only tested in Chrome, and that I'm unsure beyond that. Or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: Oh I actaully meant detect whether your standard alert dialog is being physically displayed in your browser. There's no way to programmically garantuee it is.

Answer (score 8):

No there is not. You can check that the return value of a `confirm` command is indeed `true` or `false` but you cant check whether there visually there.

These things are part of the browser not part of the DOM. I'm sure there's a dirty hack that works for IE because it's a bastardized child of the windows OS.

Comment: +1 for the fact that your second paragraph is almost definitely true.

Comment: @Moses I challenge you to find a link to the windows OS that allows you to actaully check that the alert is physically displayed in IE

Comment: There are many ways to check for this.  You can do two things that I know of - 1) inject your own handlers before `alert` or `confirm` (see answer below), or 2) set a function at an interval (`setInterval`) to find out when the last time the UI thread was unlocked (though a long lag isn't necessarilly just from an `alert()` or `confirm()` it is probably telling enough).

Comment: @DanBeam I interpreted the question as how can I ensure that an alert is displayed as intended on the client. that's only asserting that your code called the `window.alert` function. it's not in the DOM its out of your hands.

Answer (score 7):

You could do this if you want to...

```
(function () {

    // remember the normal alert
    var oldAlert = (function(){ return this.alert; }()),
        oldConfirm = (function(){ return this.confirm; }());

    // inject ourself into the window.alert and window.confirm globals
    alert = function (msg) {
        oldAlert.call(document, msg);
        document.onAlert(msg);
    };
    confirm = function (msg) {
        var result = oldConfirm.call(document, msg);
        document.onConfirm(msg, result);
        return result;
    };

    // these just chill and listen for events
    document.onAlert = function (msg) {
        window.console && console.log('someone alerted: ' + msg);
    };
    document.onConfirm = function (msg) {
        window.console && console.log('someone was asked: ' + msg);
        window.console && console.log('and they answered: ' + (msg ? 'yes' : 'no'));
    };

}());
```

The downside to this is that

- you're hacking a host method of a browser (stuff you shouldn't typically do - http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/)
- you should just be better keeping track of your `alert()` `confirm()` usage, haha

Answer (score 4):

Confirm and alert boxes are blocking events - Javascript code execution is halted while these are displayed. So no - you can not detect if one is currently being displayed, as far as I know.

Comment: This is true that they block the UI thread, but that doesn't mean you can sniff this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to detect if these are being blocked.  You will have to do your own thing with the message you will be dispalying but override the native alert/confirm.

```
window.nativeAlert = window.alert;
window.alert = function (message) {
var timeBefore = new Date();
var confirmBool = nativeAlert(message);
var timeAfter = new Date();
if ((timeAfter - timeBefore) < 350) {
    MySpecialDialog("You have alerts turned off, turn them back on or die!!!");
  }
}

window.nativeConfirm = window.confirm;
window.confirm = function (message) {
var timeBefore = new Date();
var confirmBool = nativeConfirm(message);
var timeAfter = new Date();
if ((timeAfter - timeBefore) < 350) {
    MySpecialDialog("You have alerts turned off, turn them back on or die!!!");
}
 return confirmBool;
}
```

Obviously I have set the time to 3.5 milliseconds.  But after some testing we were only able to click or close the dialogs in about 5 milliseconds plus

Comment: In the confirm() you could also return null if the timeframe is too short; this could both be detected by callers as well as looking like 'false' for most normal uses.

Comment: Overriding the return to null (or false) on too-short a timeframe can also help prevent accidental auto-confirmation when someone submits a form post but holds down the Enter key for too long.

Comment: That isn't a bad idea, but I worry about overriding the users decision, it might be that they knew there was going to be a confirm. Although I do see the advantage to doing that because that is the one loophole in doing this. Someone that can hold enter will fire off the special dialog. But it will work 99.9% of the time.

Comment: That's true; whether to force the user to read the confirmation message is probably use-case specific.

Answer (score 3):

To add to @user113716's answer you can rely on time. I assume that if confirm dialog took less than 200 ms, it is blocked by browser. Below I return true if confirm dialog is blocked (by default it returns false, the code is in TypeScript).

```
    let oldConfirm = window.confirm;
    window.confirm = (msg) => {
        let time = new Date().getTime();
        let conf = oldConfirm(msg);

        return new Date().getTime() - time > 200 ? conf : true;
    }
```