# How to detect where JavaScript alert is coming from?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to debug a very complex IE Intranet application. I am getting an alert with a custom message stating that an exception has occurred. I would like to find out more information about this exception as the message is not very helpful.

There is a master page which contains a lot of iFrames (and .htc files if that makes a difference) so I don't think that I can try and [hijack window.alert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4867114/79835). My last resort will be to try my luck with a file search.

Using IE 8, is there anyway I can detect where this alert is coming from? The ideal solution would be to somehow create a "breakOnAlert" function which inserts a debbuger statement at the correct alert location.

**To clarify:** The master page contains many iframes and I believe that the error+alert is coming from one of these. Each iframe is an aspx page (sometimes with dynamic html/javascript from the user) and contains inline and external JavaScript. Before posting I did try overriding *alert* in my page (a child page inside an iframe) but it didn't work. <strike>I am assuming that</strike> It doesn't work as each iframe has their own window object so they each have their own version of *alert*. For this to work I would need to find all iframes and override it for each one, something which I think would be very complicated to do. In the IE developer tools I can see a huge amount of script files (inline and external), so it would be very difficult to manually look for the alerts in there.

Comment: off topic, but please submit the code to thedailywtf.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it's a real chore to do it in all iframes, I'd probably use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) and programatically replace `alert(` with something like:

```
(function(n){alert(n);debugger;})(
```

IE should support the `debugger` statement, so you'd have a call-stack

[This page](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/dev/scriptsamples.asp) explains how to do a text-replace in Fiddler

Example Fiddler custom rule to add to `OnBeforeResponse`:

```
if (oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type", "html"))
{
    oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
    var oBody = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(oSession.responseBodyBytes);
    oBody = oBody.replace(/alert\(/gi, "(function(n){alert(n);debugger;})(");
    oSession.utilSetResponseBody(oBody);
}
```

Comment: Great solution. I have updated your answer (awaiting approval) with a working Fiddler rule. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ovveride alert function and set a breakpoint inside, then you can watch Stack Trace :)

```
 function alert(message) {
     var x = 'whatever';
 }


 $(function () {
     alert('test');
 });
```

Comment: Hi, as mentioned I don't think that this will work due to all the iFrames. I did try before posting the question, but I am guessing that it doesn't work because each frame will have their own window.alert() I would need to override them all.