# Javascript: Detect if an alert is already being displayed

Tags: javascript, html, blackberry, alert, blackberry-webworks

I'm working on an app in Blackberry Webworks (HTML5). I have some methods that run in background at the same time and if one of these happen to fail, an alert will be displayed by invoking JS' alert() method. If both methods fail then two alerts will be displayed --one on top of the other.

Is there any way I can avoid this? I was thinking of detecting whether an alert is already being displayed to avoid displaying the second one.

BTW: I do know that someone asked something similar ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698229/dont-show-an-alert-box-if-one-is-already-displayed)) but since that question wasn't clear enough, I had to ask it myself.

Comment: Could you clarify if you see two alerts *simultaneously* on the screen?

Comment: as far as js is concerned, there is never even a moment where an alert is being shown.

Comment: Web workers cannot communicate with each other synchronously, so no, they cannot know what the other is currently doing. You could try to delegate alert handling to a dedicated shared web worker which will receive the messages to display via postMessage, and show the alerts one after the other, but it could be overengineering.

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866986/detect-if-an-alert-or-confirm-is-displayed-on-a-page

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you can't detect if an alert, confirm or prompt box is already active.