# How to check to see if there is a window alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, alert

Is there a way to use jquery to check to see if there is an alert popup currently engaged?

I have a form that throws an alert window if there are validation errors before submit.

I need to run a function IF this alert window does not appear, however my script file is separate from the script file that throws the alert.

I can't actually go in and edit the validation function, so I am trying to write a script that loads separately.

Ideally, I'd like to run a function that says "on click of the submit button, if no alert is detected, run this function"

Any suggestions on how to detect this alert? Thank you!

Comment: I think the best route would be to wrap window.alert in some other service. This could set a flag that can be queried later. If you cannot have access to the validation method and it has no other side effects, i think you may be stuck.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866986/detect-if-an-alert-or-confirm-is-displayed-on-a-page#answer-4867114

Comment: Thanks @Joel I am going to check and see if the link PSL found works for me. Will report back.

Comment: Likely the best way to go would be to not use `alert` at all. It's pretty much obsolete, nothing but obnoxious and in most browsers tempts users to deactivate Javascript for the page.

Comment: I don't know how to close this question as I have now realized it is a duplicate... but to anyone else searching for the answer to it the best place to find info is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866986/detect-if-an-alert-or-confirm-is-displayed-on-a-page

Comment: Beneath the tags to the question, you should see a 'close' and 'delete' link (among others), clicking one of those will either close, or delete, your question if you consider it a duplicate.