# Is there a way to register for alert event in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am working with third party websites and i need to know if an window.alert was called? So my best guess is to subscribe to an alert event and that would trigger the callback for the event. I was not able to find any such events after doing some research. What are my best options?

I tried the following but it hijacks the alert event and no alert box is displayed
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3jb3s3u/)

```
window.alert = function() {
 console.log('alert');
}

alert('hello');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if an alert or confirm is displayed on a page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866986/detect-if-an-alert-or-confirm-is-displayed-on-a-page)

Comment: This code is working actually, I opened your jsfiddle and I can see the console log input "hello".

Comment: @avilac But you dont see the alert box.

Comment: @inputError it's like you're overriding the alert() functionality.

Comment: @inputError that's because you have overriding the native function. Check the question in the first comment, you have to call the old alert message inside the new one.

Comment: Your fiddle, [tweaked](https://jsfiddle.net/63bLpo6r/).

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Yes i understand that. That question does not answer as i want to know if the alert was called. similar to a `onclick` event

Comment: If you overwrite `alert`, you need to keep a reference to the original `alert` function and call that: `var orig_alert = window.alert; window.alert = function(msg) { orig_alert(msg); console.log('alert was called'); };`.

Comment: @inputError if you put a `console.log` inside it you will know when its called.

Comment: Before DownVoting please read my question. Thanks. I understand the similarity between the questions but please read it.

Comment: @inputError I respectfully suggest that you read the linked question and answers as well. It's exactly what you're asking and if there is some reason why the information does not apply to your problem it must be something that remains in your mind and didn't really share here.

Answer (score 3):

Does this helps you?

```js
var originalAlert = alert;
window.alert = function(msg) {
   console.log('alert');
   originalAlert(msg);
}

alert('hello');
```