# JavaScript - Event Listener for Alerts and Confirm boxes?

Tags: javascript, html

This may be basic, but it's something I'm not able to find the answer to.

I need to write an event listener, which listens for alerts / confirm boxes displayed on the page, and this is what they're expected to do

**When there is an alert**

1. Detect that there is an alert on the page.
2. Capture the alert message
3. Detect when the user is pressing the OK button (basically an event handler for the alert OK click)

**When there is a confirm box**

1. Detect that there's a confirm box
2. Capture the message
3. Detect what button the user is clicking. Is he/she accepting the alert, or is he/she dismissing the alert.

I need this for a side project I'm working on, which simply collects some stats from a specific web app and sends back some data for analytics. There are a lot of Confirm boxes on the page, and I would like to record the decisions taken by users.

This could be thought of as a browser extension for Firefox, Chrome and/or IE, which runs in the background and listens to user interactions and report them elsewhere.

I have gone through a post: [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866986/detect-if-an-alert-or-confirm-is-displayed-on-a-page), but it doesn't seem to answer my question.

Please help

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: `an event listener, which listens for alerts / confirm boxes displayed on the page` I don't think there is an `event` for such things

Comment: `There are a lot of Confirm boxes on the page, and I would like to record the decisions taken by users` - you wrote the "web app", so rewrite it to collect the data (you are referring to window.alert and window.confirm etc, right?)

Comment: Since `alert`, `confirm` and `prompt` are all synchronous, there are no events for them. The way to execute code after they are dismissed is to simply write the next statement in the code. `confirm` and `prompt` both have _return values_ you could check.

Comment: @JaromandaX I do not write the pages. Think of it as a browser add-on.

Comment: then , where you said it *collects some stats from **my** web app* is not an accurate description of the problem ... but, sure, that code can be put in a browser add-on - of course, nobody is going to install that browser add-on, but then, you can't force your code onto someone browsing someone else's web page - there's a term for that

Comment: You could simply overwrite those functions with your own implementation that does the stuff you want and calls the original (native) implementation

Comment: @Bergi When you way "overwrite" those functions, do you mean overwriting the alert() and confirm() functions? If that's possible, then yes that'd solve my problem. Can you point me in a direction I can take to achieve this? How do I overwrite these functions?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, probably my statement is wrong. As I said, it's a side project, and I can't meddle with my application's code. I'll rephrase my question accordingly. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: `If that's possible, then yes that'd solve my problem. Can you point me in a direction I can take to achieve this?` - well that's exactly what I showed you in that jsfiddle

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry I did not realize. Thanks, i'll try it out!