# Is there anyway to detect alert with javascript?

Tags: javascript

Currently im new to javascript and i've face some problem when i got an idea for my assignment.

I dont know if we can detect alert with javascript or not?

I searched and i found this topic but its not helped much.
[Detect if an alert or confirm is displayed on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866986/detect-if-an-alert-or-confirm-is-displayed-on-a-page)

My problem when i try to solve captcha with my script: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NbHT.png

I expected :
If our script detect "Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again."

We will refresh the page and check then try to solve captcha again.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "detect alert". Are you talking about the `alert` function? If yes, what exactly do you want to detect?

Comment: This one : "Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again" I got some connection problem so i need to check the alert is there and we'll reload the page.

Comment: If it's a message that is displayed with `alert` I doubt there is anything you can do since `alert` is blocking, i.e. no other JavaScript is executed as a long as the alert window is open.

Comment: Oh thats make sense :)  thanks :)

Comment: I think `alert` here doesn't refer to `window.alert`, but that kind of `message bar` within the frame.

Comment: An [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?

Comment: So I would suggest taking `Maxim Pyshko`'s first advice. A simple intervaled check on the existence/display of the `alert` elements will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

I think you will not be able to know and run any script when alert have been opened.
Open your console and run interval to test it:

```
setInterval(() => console.log('test'), 1000);
```

And then run:

```
alert(1);
```

You will see that interval will not log 'test' until you close the alert.

To do that you want, you may need to create another application that will work in another tab and send to it post messages. If that another application will detect timeout - then you could reload the page.

**Update**

Or you can override alert and reload page when alert is calling:

```
window.alert = () => location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/btckqe0p/7/). I do a hack on the alert function, then you can check the message to inject your stuff.

```
(function (window) {
    const _alert = window.alert
    window.alert = (message) => {
        window.onAlert && window.onAlert(message, _alert)
    }
})(window)

function createRecaptcha() {
    grecaptcha.render("recaptcha", {sitekey: "6LcgSAMTAAAAACc2C7rc6HB9ZmEX4SyB0bbAJvTG", theme: "light"});
}

createRecaptcha();

window.onAlert = (message, alert) => {
  if(message === 'Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again.') {
    // do your stuffs, for example:
    document.body.innerHTML = '<h1>The alert is injected</h1>'
    return
  }

  alert(message)
}
alert('application alert')
```

Answer (score 0):

Interest question, i have some simple solution to prevent alert. 
 First i collect and remember what is origin alert prototype method.
 That i override alert. Other procedure is simple...

```js
window["cloneOriginAlert"] = alert;

alert = function (msg, prevent) { 
    
          if ( typeof prevent !== 'undefined') { return; }
    
          var test = prompt("You wanna see alert ? ", "Alert is comming !!! "); 
     
          if (test != null) {
             console.warn("Alert is allowed here ! ", msg)
             window["cloneOriginAlert"](msg);   
          } else {
            console.log("No alert here")
          }
          
    }  
    
    alert("Hello bug")
```

I hope this is what you want!