# How to detect browsers notification

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, browser, notifications

How to detect Chrome browser notification?

I don't mean my own application's notification, but any notification

Is there a way to just tell that the browser got a notification *(without its details)*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect if an alert or confirm is displayed on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866986/detect-if-an-alert-or-confirm-is-displayed-on-a-page)

Comment: No. I’m talking about the browser notification (Chrome)